# Best position to attach a Sub-Panel neutral feeder cable lug kit

Tags: electrical-panel

to feed a subpanel, is there a preferable position where to attach the neutral feeder cable lug kit into? I will keep neutral and ground separate. I will attach the 100A feeder breaker to the top left position. I wonder if there is a preferable position on where to attach the neutral feeder lug kit to.

Does the feeder neutral lug need to stay as close as possible, or at least on the same neutral bus bar, as the entrance service neutral cable?

As you can see in the picture, my Right bus bar is quite crowded and I was planning to put the sub-panel neutral feeder lug kit on the bottom of the left neutral bus bar.

Should I instead lock it to the bottom of the Right bus bar and reposition some of those neutral wires? THX

[image]

Comment: They make a double lug that can replace your existing single lug. Or The lug can go at the bottom if you like I would give other options but I see no main breaker so your main is actually a sub. Good thing that everything is separate as far as ground and neutral, make sure to kill the power if you change to a double lug, at that point the return path can be just as lethal as a hot if circuits are in use. Kill the power or all the breakers in the panel and the neutral is safe. 
I prefer the double lug kit to me it makes the most sense.

Comment: Good catch, this panel it's on itself a sub and as such the neutral is not bonded the ground. I just did not want to get into that ;) and YES very good point, I was planning on it but for everyone reading the neutral can be just as dangerous as any of the hot and the main disconnect outside will be and should be off the whole time. THX

Comment: This is  not posted as an answer because I don't know for sure what item you are installing and I can't find a double wire lug in the catalog (it may still exist). The instructions that come with a NL20 lug http://pdf.lowes.com/productdocuments/5bf2cdf3-a93c-460a-8016-03a07ef8bfc6/09198036.pdf say "remove (3) wire pressure screws adjacent to existing main lug". Instructions are part of the (UL) Listing, and NEC requires installing per those instruction. You will need to check the instruction for the product you buy.

Answer (score 1):

I note that you're using a lug kit.

It doesn't matter, the neutral bar is UL listed for full current to be drawn in any position on it.  If you are looking for things to do to improve safety, top of the list is actually to use a torque wrench or driver to set the screw torques to spec. Mis-torqued lugs and screws cause panel damage all the time, and that's why using a torque driver is now a Code requirement.

I note major home stores have a 1/4" drive beam-type torque wrench with a suitable 0-100 inch-pound range for about $25. That with a bit holder,  you should be all set.

Comment: This is not accurate the holes in the bar will not accept over a number 6 in most cases an additional large lug is required for a 100A feeder

Comment: @EdBeal Look closely at the question, OP states the intent of using a **lug kit**.  This has a large lug and 2-3 fingers designed to go into 2-3 adjacent holes in the neutral bar.  This is the manufacturer (and UL) approved method.

Comment: THNAK YOU and Yes: I do have a torque wrench and will use it to spec. Also the lug kit will be able to host up to a #2AWG the same size of my aluminum feeding cables. THX again

Comment: You state any position and that is not the case for most lug kits and with the buss being full it further restricts the locations unless the same location as the single lug .